# How to make one TextBox to update when ComboBox changes in .NET?

Tags: c#, winforms

Following is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Eventmanagement
{
    public partial class Registration : Form
    {
        SqlConnection aConnection;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dta;

        public Registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        //--------------------------------------------//

        private void Registration_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'insertEventDataSet.Events' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

            populateEventSalesPersonList();
            populateEventNameIdTypeList();

            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//
            txtSalesTaxRate_Registration.Text = Convert.ToString( SalesTaxRate() +"%");

            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//
            txtSalesTax_Registration.Text = Convert.ToString(saleTax());
            txtTotalCharges_Registration.Text = Convert.ToString(totalCharges());
            txtAmountDue_Registration.Text = Convert.ToString(amountDue());
            //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++//



        }

        //--------------------------------------------//

        public string getConnectionString()
        {
            try
            {
                string sConnection = "";

                // Get the mapped configuration file.
                System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettingsCollection ConnSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
                sConnection = ConnSettings["DBConnectionString"].ToString();

                return sConnection;


            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }



        //--------------------------------------------//
        public void populateEventNameIdTypeList()
        {
            try
            {
                cmbEvent_Registration.DataSource = getDataTable4();
                //----------------------------
                cmbEvent_Registration.ValueMember = "EventID";
                cmbEvent_Registration.DisplayMember = "EventName";




            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }


        }


        //--------------------------------------------//

        public void populateEventSalesPersonList()
        {
             try
            {

                cmbSalesPerson_Registration.DataSource = getDataTable5();
                cmbSalesPerson_Registration.ValueMember = "EmployeeID";
                cmbSalesPerson_Registration.DisplayMember = "SalesPerson";

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }
        }

        //-------------------------------------------//

        public void populateFeeScheduleByEventList()
        {

            try
            {

                cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.DataSource = getDataTable6();
                cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.ValueMember = "FeeScheduleID";
                cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.DisplayMember = "Fee";
                cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.Text = cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.SelectedText.ToString();
                }

            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }

        }

        //------------------------------------------//

        //------------------------------------------//



        private void btnclose_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btnInsert_Registration_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
                aConnection.Open();

                //Calling the Stored Procedure

                da.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("RegistrationInsert", aConnection);
                da.InsertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"RegistrationDate", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtRegistrationDate_Registration.Text.ToString());
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"PurchaseOrderNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPoNumber_Registration.Text; 
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"SalesPerson", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt64(cmbSalesPerson_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString());
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbEvent_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString();
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"FeeScheduleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString();
                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"RegistrationFee", SqlDbType.Money).Value = txtRegistrationFee_Registration.Text;

                da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"SalesTaxRate", SqlDbType.Float).Value = txtSalesTaxRate_Registration.Text;
                //da.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add(@"EndTime", SqlDbType.SmallDateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEndTime.Text.ToString());
                da.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();


                MessageBox.Show("Inserted successfully!!!");

                aConnection.Close();
                da.InsertCommand.Dispose();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
            }


        }

        //-------------------------------------------//

        public DataTable getDataTable4()
        {
            try
            {
                dta = new DataTable();
                aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
                aConnection.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("EventsSelectAll", aConnection);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                da.Fill(dta);
                aConnection.Close();
                return dta;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        public DataTable getDataTable5()
        {
            try
            {
                dta = new DataTable();
                aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
                aConnection.Open();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_RegistrationSalesPerson", aConnection);
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dta.Clear();
                da.Fill(dta);
                aConnection.Close();
                return dta;

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }
        public DataTable getDataTable6()
        {
            try
            {
                dta = new DataTable();
                da = new SqlDataAdapter();
                aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());

                aConnection.Open();

                da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("sp_FeeScheduleSelectAllByEventID", aConnection);
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbEvent_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString());
                da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                da.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                da.Fill(dta);
                aConnection.Close();
                return dta;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
                return null;
            }


        }



        private void cmbEvent_Registration_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                populateFeeScheduleByEventList();
                txtRemainingSeats_Registration.Text = Convert.ToString(spaces());
        }





        private void cmbFeeSchedule_Registration_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtRegistrationFee_Registration.Text = cmbFeeSchedule_Registration.Text.ToString();


        }
        public int totalRegisteredAttendees()
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("RegistrationSelectAllByEventID", aConnection);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbEvent_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString());

            aConnection.Open();
            int val = (int)da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            aConnection.Close();
            return val;
        }
        public int spaces()
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("EventsSelect", aConnection);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("EventID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(cmbEvent_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString());
           // MessageBox.Show(cmbEvent_Registration.SelectedValue.ToString());
            aConnection.Open();

            int spaces = Convert.ToInt16(da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            aConnection.Close();

            int value = totalRegisteredAttendees();
            int totalspaces = spaces - value;
            return totalspaces;

        }

        public double SalesTaxRate()
        {
            da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            aConnection = new SqlConnection(getConnectionString());
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("CompanyInfo", aConnection);
            da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            aConnection.Open();
            double sale = Convert.ToDouble(da.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar());
            aConnection.Close();
            return sale;
        }

        public void updateSaleTax()
        {

        }

        public double saleTax()
        {
            double regFee = Convert.ToDouble(txtRegistrationFee_Registration.Text.ToString());
            double sTR = Convert.ToDouble(SalesTaxRate());
            double sr = regFee * (sTR / 100);
            return sr;
       }
        public double totalCharges()
        {
            double tc = Convert.ToDouble(txtRegistrationFee_Registration.Text.ToString()) +  (saleTax());
            return tc;
        }
        public double amountDue()
        {
            double aD;
            if (txtTotalPaid_Registration.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                aD = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotalCharges_Registration.Text.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                double a = Convert.ToDouble(txtTotalPaid_Registration.Text.ToString());
                 double b=    (Convert.ToDouble(txtTotalCharges_Registration.Text.ToString()));
                 aD = b-a;
            }
                return aD;
        }

        private void txtSalesTaxRate_Registration_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void gpRegistraton_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I want saleTax to update when

```
txtRegistrationFee_Registration.Text.ToString()
```

changes, so basically I want to reconnect the whole thing. Please Help.

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as C#.NET. The language is named C#

Answer (score 2):

You could hook up your `txtRegistrationFee_Registration` with a `TextChanged` event. The event handler can call `saleTax()`.

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I last worked in Winforms. But doesn't textbox provide TextChange event? Maybe that event has different name. But there must be event that fires whenever You change text.

And when You want to get data from textbox it's just `textbox.Text`. You don't need to call `textbox.Text.ToString()`. Text is already a string.